# CS1061'WidgetFactory<IndexModel>' doesn't contain a definition for 'PDFViewer' & no accessible extension method could be found

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

I keep getting this compiler error and I.m not sure how to solve it. I can't seem to find the 'WidgetFactory'. Please see the attachment below for more information on the error.
[CS1061 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJhzs.png)

I checked the index Model  but could not find the PDFViewer instance.